# Cakephp parameters not passing

Tags: cakephp

I've spent a bunch of time trying to figure this problem out and had zero luck. I have tried routing with no success. I'll put the logic first then the code.

> 1. Users are in /pra/Fields/view/1 looking at a list of fields where fields.template_id=1
> 2. Users click add new field /pra/Fields/add_new/1 they are brought to a form where they enter the information they want to
>      about the new field they create.
> 3. when a user clicks on add/submit, the new field is saved to the database
> 4. The user is taken back to /pra/Fields/view/1 so they can see the new field added to the template

currently the first 3 steps are happening, however when it comes to redirecting back to `/pra/Fields/view/1` The user is being redirected to `/pra/Fields/view/`

here is the code for the add_new function

```
function add_new($id=null){
    //allows users to add another field to an existing template
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Create Fields');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');
    $this->layout='home_layout';
    $name=$this->Field->field('template_id', array('template_id'=>$id));
    //if the field data saves
    $this->set('name',$name);
    if(($this->Field->save($this->data)))
    {   
        //user is redirected to fields/view/$name
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Fields', 'action'=>'view',$name));
    }
    //sets the $id variable
    $this->set('id',$id);
```

here is the add_new view

```
<table id="formatform">
        </br></br>
        <?php
            $options = array('Money'=>'Money','Text'=>'Text','Description'=>'Description');
            ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->create('Field', array('action'=>'add_new')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('id',array('type'=>'hidden')); ?>
                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('template_id',array('type'=>'hidden','default' => $id)); ?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td align='center'>Field Name:</td>
                <td align='left'><?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label'=>false)); ?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td align='center'>Default Value:</td>
                <td align='left'><?php echo $this->Form->input('default_value', array('label'=>false)); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align='center'>Field Type:</td>
                <td align='left'><?php echo $this->Form->input('field_type', array('label'=>false,'type'=>'select','options'=>$options)); ?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td align='center'>Description:</td>
                <td align='left'><?php echo $this->Form->input('description', array('label'=>false)); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('active', array('type'=>'hidden','default'=>true)); ?></td>
                </tr>




    <td></td>   <td align = "left"><?php echo $this->Form->end('Submit');?></td>
```

and here is the view function code

```
function view($name){
    //lists information about fields that correspond to the
    //template they have clicked 'view' on
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Field Details');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');
    $this->layout='home_layout';
    //sets $conditions where template_id=$name and field.active=true
    $conditions=array(
        "AND"=>array(
        'template_id'=> $name,
        'Field.active'=>true));
    //finds all fields where 'conditions'=$conditions
    $fields = $this->Template->Field->find('all',array( 
        'conditions' => $conditions));
    //sets all the variables      
    $this->set('conditions', $conditions);
    $this->set('field', $fields);
    $this->set('field', $this->paginate('Field', $conditions));  


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might happen that you have an issue here:

```
function add_new($id=null){
    //allows users to add another field to an existing template
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Create Fields');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');
    $this->layout='home_layout';
```

Check if $name is not empty

```
$name = $this->Field->field('template_id', array('template_id'=>$id)); 
if(!empty($name)){
    $this->set('name',$name);
    if(($this->Field->save($this->data)))
    {   
        //user is redirected to fields/view/$name
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Fields', 'action'=>'view',$name));
    }
}
```

the rest of your code

```
//sets the $id variable
$this->set('id',$id);
```

Comment: no luck, when I click submit it doesn't save to the database or redirect :(

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_new($id=null){
    //allows users to add another field to an existing template
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Create Fields');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');
    $this->layout='home_layout';
    $this->set('id',$id);

    if(($this->Field->save($this->data)))
    {

    $id = $this->data['Field']['template_id'];

    $this->set('id',$id);
    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Fields', 'action'=>'view',$id));

    }
    }
```